# How to get javascript intellisense when using Url.Content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

Say I add a link to jQuery as follows in MVC3

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jq.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now the scripts folder also has the -vsdoc file but I won't get the intellisense unless I add the script file like this:

```
<script src="../../JS/jq.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature is not supported. Read *Section 4*. *Which URL-path types does IntelliSense recognize?* in this [**page**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/18/jscript-intellisense-faq.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I keep the "real" jquery.min file loaded in my master/_layout page, and then I just throw this up at the top of the child page for jQuery intellisense (razor code):

```
@if (false) { <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5-vsdoc.js"></script> }
```